Convergence to Independent Gaussian Processes
Suppose $(X_n(t):t \in [0,1])_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(Y_n(t):t \in [0,1]))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are two sequences of stochastic processes taking values in $C([0,1])$ (equipped with uniform topology). Suppose $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to $Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two Gaussian processes taking values $C([0,1])$.
My question is the following in: If we also know for each $t,s \in [0,1]$, the vector $(X_n(t),Y_n(s))$ converges in distribution to $(Z^1(t),Z^2(s))$ with $Z^1(t) \stackrel{d}{=} X(t)$, $Z^2(s) \stackrel{d}{=}Y(s)$, and $Z^1(t) \perp Z^2(s)$. Does it imply $((X_n(t),Y_n(t)): t \in [0,1])$ converge in distribution to some Gaussian process $((Z^1(t),Z^2(t)): t \in [0,1])$ with $Z^1 \stackrel{d}{=} X$, $Z^2 \stackrel{d}{=}Y$ and $Z^1 \perp Z^2$? Or does it imply weak convergence to $(Z^1,Z^2)$ under some regularity condition on modulus of continuity?
I known normally to check the weak convergence of $(X_n, Y_n)$ to $(Z^1, Z^2)$, we would need to check for the convergence of finite dimensional distribution and tightness of $(X_n,Y_n)$. I wonder in the Gaussian case whether checking pairwise weak convergence $(X_n(t),Y_n(s))$ is enough.
